# Crear copia de seguridad de PostgreSQL desde Python

Tags: python, postgresql, cmd, seguridad, pyqt

Buen dia, estoy haciendo un CRUD desde Python con Postgresql, quiero realizar copias de seguridad esporadicamente para poder guardar los registros de mi cliente. Para ello, hago uso de la siguiente función:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -F c test_oficina > test_oficina1005
```

Luego de ingresar ese pequeño script al cmd, me indica que debo ingresar la contraseña de mi BDD, la cual en mi caso es "12345". Sin embargo, quiero hacer que ésta se ingrese tambien de manera automatica, adjunto codigo con el cual realizo estas funciones.

```
import subprocess

def cmd(comando):
    resultado = subprocess.run(comando, shell=True)

cmd('pg_dump -U postgres -F c test_oficina > test_oficina1005')
```

Una vez ejecuto ese script, el CMD se queda esperando a que ingrese la contraseña para poder crear la copia de seguridad, lo cual no seria correcto para el cliente.

Comment: ¿Y si creas un archivo .bat y lo ejecutas cada cierto tiempo desde windows task scheduler?

Comment: Es buena idea, pero me surge la duda de cual codigo debo usar para ejecutar el ingreso de la contraseña de mi BDD

Answer (score 1):

Viendo la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html):

```
-W
--password

    Force pg_dump to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.

    This option is never essential, since pg_dump will automatically prompt for a password if the server demands password authentication. However, pg_dump will waste a connection attempt finding out that the server wants a password. In some cases it is worth typing -W to avoid the extra connection attempt.
```

Entonces la orden sería:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -F -W "micontraseña" c test_oficina > test_oficina1005
```